# How to create customized ruleset using the codenarc plugin?

Tags: grails, groovy, codenarc

I am currently using the `codenarc plugin`, and I wanted to customize the codenarc ruleset property for it to check the proper indentation of my codes.

Have anyone tried this?

Please help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

CodeNarc does not (currently) include any rules for checking/enforcing code indentation. Though you are welcome to contribute one!

You can see a list of all rules at:
http://codenarc.sourceforge.net/codenarc-rule-index.html

The formatting rules are described at:
http://codenarc.sourceforge.net/codenarc-rules-formatting.html

Chris

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Indentation` rule. This is included in `rulesets/formatting.xml`. This will check the indentation (spaces only; not tabs) for class, field and method declarations, and statements. The default is 4 spaces per indentation level, This is configurable via the `spacesPerIndentLevel` property. See [this page](https://codenarc.github.io/CodeNarc/codenarc-rules-formatting.html) for details.

With the rule enabled violations are reported like this, in the default HTML report:
[Example report showing violations of the 'Indentation' rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0aJ5R.png).